# Can topology be studied without $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, self-learning

My friend is a programmer who works with countable math objects (like countable graphs, or groups). He often reads the professional literature where a lot of topological concepts are mentioned. That's why he's trying to study topology on his own. Alas, in those textbooks, there are a lot of examples concerning $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, since he usually works with countable objects, he starts thinking that not much of the concepts would be helpful. Can he omit the examples with $\mathbb{R}$ without loss of generality? Are there general or algebraic topology textbooks where all such examples are omitted, i.e. they are concentrated on finitistic objects?

Comment: a bit opinion based, but I would say no. topology is about limits; sure you can take limits in a countable set, but it sounds more like combinatorics

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki anyway, your comment is helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not such a silly idea:  there's a theorem of McCord (https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/mccord1.pdf) that every finite simplicial complex is weak homotopy equivalent to a finite topological space.  See also Peter May's book on finite topological spaces:  https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/FINITEBOOK/FINITEBOOKCollatedDraft.pdf

Comment: In a way, $\Bbb R$ is "almost countable": it has a countable dense subset. If you're mainly interesting in continuous objects, then understanding them on a dense subset is enough.

Comment: It is possible, though it would be hard to find a topology book that does not base many examples on the reals. I think I may have seen such a book, but could not quickly find one now, but the following might be of interest https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106610580221X One could also google things like domain theory and topology (though some results are more theoretical, don't know what would be of interest to your friend). The short answer, yes it could definitely be done, but one has to look for it. (Re the reals, $1/n$ could well replace $\varepsilon$ most of the time)

Comment: I highly disagree with the claim that "topology is about limits".

Comment: Just another comment: The question whether your friend could "omit the examples with $\mathbb{R}$ without loss of generality", the answer may depend not so much on $\mathbb{R}$, but on what topological concepts these examples clarify and illustrate. Also (just teasing) I think programmers are supposed to only work with finite objects, and if they could make the leap to work with countable, why not go a bit further to work with $\mathbb{R}$? For interesting T$_0$ topologies on a finite set w applications to computer graphics see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419090031V

Comment: @Mirko thanks for your answer and links. I wonder what kind of mathematics Dedekind or Cantor would do if they lived today...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and very useful to build an intuition of topology without $\mathbb R$. It is possible to view topology as capturing data about *semi-decidability*. If your friend knows Haskell (it's a very math-influenced purely functional programming language), ask them to read [Martín Escardó's so-called Barbados notes, number 46 in `https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/index.html`](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/papers/index.html), AKA "[Synthetic topology of data types and classical spaces](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272990/1-s2.0-S1571066104X00177/1-s2.0-S1571066104051357/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHwaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCUHPaMhXIxR5ntki261HQ0rfhfVOSKmrZnxQxCu8EbLAIgaUrO%2B1NOieevNSJgqIYxGmF7aXB7G5WDxBHhLuIfRtkqtAMINBADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDLXEqlNcrvWx8rgxqCqRA5WHSCrlPlhL8rxOK2qpHmVb0zZkNi7EyP%2B4WI8mXy5u8khz%2BkpXVCmjBj3ZCFbrZfsvl%2FecroIhcYDVqQSl7we4AVyXwW3Zb79Go%2F8Nz1%2FtIJOK0GELEKGbI%2FM4rZwRvVtJBsUn64xjP6lHBrLZOXAkC%2ByXlTZDlTRxfAlHYZURRLcGv8h8o%2BYWXb2d0eOIsMx5yMyXxM%2FZ5aUjcxoXaj3N5hNPo5bjni1aHfLEfEDRZlxbdszxRLVuzvbmTxAnychD7O202VANV3vr8JRdDcNTCmmrxl3yUYvmYrnmiFSM0u4C1bwtAyy4cYM%2FJNDpGLyYTGdxHDwVALblPBWVZxBN2VAFcCohCxCZjNXyFQ2nLZdaLFkLdYxPLJ3ktfBCMhduf0BFvWZIkwqJM3qo2u6Wli0e9j1eo3%2FyyJg026sKigWl04CzDgwD6hQdnENdQrSC%2BkrfJUuPfkkROcrh1IBtCXARS2v5BS2uglERQoeS2SFFo2Lh1C3fv%2BwDtAtE7Dd50tKrrMTeyev11%2BXzc0aQMIm7o%2F8FOusBLyr9%2ByezwCA4qaqn4Jr2vulLMV98FrevmpbLYcsqtUGmohhFj%2FkAbiMowIUsoguogKowqjjM3fKB8luUlJMzdP%2F5v3zI0LFDmdqxpLvHhtK%2FATJOyhTL9bJm3QRSmNyaYZAP4vEj%2Bb6Ih7my0jhd6dIqeem7P8sb66PLUNJK3nJq7C7RaBRjlfukFbOLmf1zpiGnv%2FSPJNn%2Bz1aEJgTazVih5WnjozllOW9FnpOfr7qTXybBtGW3edcPD36DagRwZNx8%2Fr38fxITNWSoTOJtJ%2BchN7Ne4NvFlB%2FvaRUZLKLSM4PW16Xr4Hfthg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201227T202705Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY376YV3HK%2F20201227%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=33198b49665d78c6443ed6053122b6f94e23223142de95353bb275224b7392ee&hash=1bd7e2be21ff0c16f5b4f835ae4d6feb278d9d3e7223273f2b7eccf56e0fa83a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1571066104051357&tid=spdf-205b519b-5eaf-41e9-8e18-b6dc0536de14&sid=10069daf2e0ff3406118641-573fbfb7c5f5gxrqb&type=client)".

The general idea is that the open sets in the topology are those properties which we can decide *are true in finite time*, but cannot decide if they *are false in finite time*.

To expand, the topology on $\mathbb R$ allows us to semi-decide if a point $p$ belongs to some interval $I$ when we are able to access the point $p$ one digit at a time. For example, let's pick $I = (0, 1)$.

- Now, if we see a point $p = 0.1\dots$ we know immediately that this point is in $I$, so we can answer that $p \in_? I = \texttt{TRUE}$.
- If we see a point $p = 2.\dots$, we know immediately that this point $p$ is *not* in $I$, so we can answer $p \in_? I = \texttt{FALSE}$
- Now consider the point $p = 0.9999\dots$ When do we decide that this point $p$ does *not* belong to $I$?

  - we can't decide after seeing two digits $(0.9\dots)$, for the point $p$ could be $0.98$ and it would then belong to $I$
  - we can't decide after seeing  three digits ($0.99\dots)$, for the point $p$ could be $0.998$ and it would then belong to $I$
  - in general, we would need to read the *entire number* $0.999\dots$ to decide that $p \not \in I$. Clearly, this takes infinite time!

So, if $p \in I$, then we will always answer $p \in_? I = \texttt{TRUE}$ in finite time. But if $p \not \in I$, then we may not answer $p \in_? I = \texttt{FALSE}$ in finite time. Hence, the relation $\in_?$ is *semi-dedicable*, and the topology of $\mathbb R$ precisely captures the semi-decidable nature of membership in an interval.

More broadly speaking, discrete topology is vital to computer science, since [finite topology is the study of preorders and partial orders](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44135/123769). This is precisely the notion that is necessary to assign *mathematical meaning* to computer programs, through a branch of mathematics called as [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics)

I've written some blog posts about these issues that may be of some help to get started, since I collect links as well:

- [Topology is really about computation](http://bollu.github.io/topology-is-really-about-computation-part-1.html)
- [Finite topologies and DFS numbers](http://bollu.github.io/finite-topologies-and-dfs-numbering.html)

Comment: “Open sets are those properties which we… cannot decide if they are false in finite time.” is not strictly correct, and in this context could be confusing.  We cannot _necessarily_ decide the complement of an open property, but it might be both closed and open.  I'm sure you understand this, but I think you should fix the phrasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It's a really useful remark that the category of finite spaces is equivalent to the one of finite preorders.